# Computing $T'\times T''$ in terms of the Darboux vector.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics

I'm trying to show that $T ' \times T ''= kw$ where $k$ is curvature and $w$ is the Darboux vector.

I know $T' = w  \times T$. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** first write $w=aT+bN+cB$ and use the definition of the Darboux vector (those three equations, yes) to solve for  $a$, $b$ and $c$ in terms of the curvature and torsion of the curve. Then use the Frenet equations to compute $T'\times T''$ and recognize in the result the expression for $w$ you previously found.

---

A further hint: since $(T,N,B)$ is a positive orthonormal basis, the following relations hold: $$T\times N=B,\qquad N\times B=T,\qquad B\times T=N. $$

Comment: I sloved for omega in terms of torsion and curvature. my question now is that, is it okay to assume that if T' = kN then T" = kN'

Comment: No. You must use the product rule: $T''=k'N+kN'$.

Comment: got you, because i cannot assume that curvature is constant

Comment: so the problem boils down to solving kN x (k'N + kN)?

Comment: Yes (you forgot a ' in the last $N$). I added in the answer some relations you'll need. Good luck.

Comment: yes indeed. thank you